# Appending a list inside a if condition

Tags: python

I have the following code. It runs for every frame in the video. I have a list I want to append but it is not appending the value.

```
iou_value = oneObject.intersection_over_union(image,humanRegion_bbs,belongings_bbs) 
iou_list = []    
if currentFrameIndex < 400 and iou_value is not None \
   and iou_value > th_iou :
    logger.info("IOU value %f"%iou_value)              
    logger.info("CURRENT FRAME INDEX %f" %currentFrameIndex)
    iou_list.append(iou_list)

    if len(iou) > 10 :
        oneObject.setBelongings(belongingsList)
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Are you sure the code gets into if block?

Comment: yes . I have checked the log.It gets into the block

Comment: list got appended only once

Comment: You didn't show all your code. Is your `iou_list` actually positioned where it's shown, with an outer for block? Because then you'd be recreating it on each iteration, which means you'd only see one value in it (the last one) at the end of execution. You'd need to create the list outside of the for loop for that to work.

Comment: Also you should use `extend()` instead of `append()` if you want to grow a list by another list, but I don't understand why you're appending the list to itself in the first place.

Comment: by mistake, I was appending to the same list. I have corrected the code

Comment: `iou_list.append(iou_list)` appends an empty list to itself. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: `iou_list.append(iou_value)` maybe you are trying to do this but instead you have done `iou_list.append(iou_list)`